# numpy vectorization functions

Tags: python, function, numpy, vectorization

I want to use vectorization to do some computation on `numpy.ndarray`. Suppose I have the following vectorized function:

```
import numpy as np
fun = lambda x:x[0]+x[1]
fun = np.vectorize(fun)
```

and the following `numpy.ndarray`

```
 a = range(10)
 b = range(10)
 c = np.array([a,b])
```

When I apply

```
 result = fun(c)
```

I obtain the following error

```
 IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

\Why is this the case and how should I fix it?

Comment: Don't use `np.vectorize` if you are looking for performance. Look into `ufuncs` rather.

Comment: What do you expect `fun` to do? A vectorized function will apply to *every element* of an array, so how is `x[0] + x[1]` suppose to work when `x` is  a number? Also, I second the call not to use `np.vectorize`, it's essentially a thin wrapper around a vanilla Python loop.

Answer (score 1):

`np.vectorize` feeds scalar values to your function.  It iterates on the input arrays, broadcasting if needed, and feeds `func` scalars, not arrays or lists.  It then collects the values in a new array of shape and dtype that it deduces.

For example:

```
In [108]: fun = lambda x,y: x+y
     ...: fun = np.vectorize(fun)

In [110]: a=np.arange(10); b=np.arange(10)
In [111]: fun(a,b)
Out[111]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

It is not 'vectorize' in the sense of turning your function into fast compiled code.  It's a convenience, saving you some work in setting up an interation.

I'm sure your `fun` is just a example, but as written it is already 'vectorized'

```
In [112]: (lambda x,y: x+y)(a,b) 
Out[112]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

Expressing your calculation with numpy primitives, without iteration, is the true 'vectorization'.  That isn't always possible, but if you feel you must fall back on `np.vectorize` remember that

- it feeds scalars
- it will iterate at Python speeds
- use `otypes` if possible